# Issue with Selenium: Inconsistent Behavior with Multiple Browser Windows

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the provided context, I encountered an issue while using Selenium with my regular Google Chrome profile. Specifically, when I attempt to launch Selenium in a separate window while my browser is already open (without connecting to an existing session), it fails to retrieve cookies and other profile-related information.

Interestingly, starting Selenium before manually opening the browser seems to resolve the issue. However, if I open the browser while Selenium is already running, it does not retain the cache, such as the login status on Steam or the volume settings on YouTube videos. Strangely, logging into a Google account remains unaffected.

I am seeking assistance from anyone who has encountered and resolved a similar problem. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Please find below the code I am currently using:

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Server\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9223")
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

As a beginner in Selenium, this behavior is new to me, and most of the solutions I have come across involve connecting to an existing session, which is not suitable for my case. Unfortunately, I haven't found a specific solution that addresses this particular issue. Any assistance or insights would be highly appreciated.

BTW:
If I use

```py
"C:\\Users\\Server\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\UserData\\Default"
```

instead of

```py
"C:\\Users\\Server\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
```

the cookies are not transmitted to Selenium